# Remove space between "Theorem" and theorem number when using ntheorem

Tags: spacing, theorems, ntheorem

I am using the [`ntheorem`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/ntheorem?lang=en) package for hypotheses and subhyotheses (i.e. H1a, H1b, etc.), with the latter being unimportant for my problem. Just as an info for you to understand why I cannot simply use the amsthm package.

My code gives me **H 1** instead of **H1** as output, and I want to remove that space between "H" and "1". Find a screenshot attached. Thank you!!

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ntheorem}
\newtheorem{hyp}{H}     %I tried \newtheorem{hyp}{H\ignorespaces} - not working

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
The higher the mountain the harder the hike.
\end{hyp}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You will need to define your own theorem style. The default, you show here, is called plain, look in `ntheorem.sty` for the code for plain, copy it and adjust accordingly.

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfect! If you wanna give that as an answer instead of a comment I can put that question on "solved".

Comment: I don't collect point, why don't you write one yourself, good exercise (plus I'm on a tablet, so interacting with the site is rather slow)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to daleif's helpful comment I was able to solve the question by creating a `\newtheoremstyle`, based on the default style "plain" found in `ntheorem.sty`.

Plain style:

```
\newtheoremstyle{plain}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1\ ##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
```

One can see that the space occurs because of the space in `##1\ ##2`, so changing `##1\ ##2` to `##1##2` solved my problem.

This leads to the following corrected MWE:

```
\documentclass{scrreprt}

\usepackage{ntheorem} 

\makeatletter %
\newtheoremstyle{hypotheses}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1##2\theorem@separator]}%
  {\item[\hskip\labelsep \theorem@headerfont ##1##2\ (##3)\theorem@separator]}
\makeatother

\theoremstyle{hypotheses}
\newtheorem{hyp}{H} 

\begin{document}

\begin{hyp}
The higher the mountain the harder the hike.
\end{hyp}

\end{document}
```

with the output:

[image]

Hope this might help some of you in the future as well.

Comment: Btw you should probably name the plain style you show plain, and not hypotheses, more instructive give your explanation after it.